# Ng-model input as array

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I have this input repeating based on my items `['1','2']`, then ng-model for input:

```html
<form id="register-form" form ng-submit="successbloodstock.updateRemark()" >
      <div class="input-group input-group">
         <div class="input-group-addon" style="width:130px">
           <small>EXPIRATION DATE</small>
         </div>
         <input class="form-control"  type="date"  name="expiry_date" 
                ng-model="newExpiry"  required>
      </div>
</form>
```

but after I submit the form it doesn't show the ng-model as array:

```
.controller('successbloodstockCtrl', function($scope,$timeout,$location,$route,$routeParams,$http) {
  var app = this;
  app.number=['asdf','asadf'];
  app.updateRemark = function() {
    var userObject = {}; 
    userObject.expiry_date = $scope.newExpiry;
    console.log($scope.newExpiry[$index])
  }
}
```

this gives me undefined

Comment: Can you please give a full code where you define your model. It's not clear from your question what 's going on.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Thanks but I still don't see where you define your repeating inputs based on which model? number? It's not in use. newExpiry is just undefined, may be it's worth to define it somewhere. But it will be just a string value, not an array.